# Windows 7 Upgrade keeps rolling back to Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

I finally decided that I would update my desktop from Windows Vista SP2 64-bit to Windows 7 64-bit.  So I got my Windows 7 Professional 64-bit DVD, popped it into my PC, and started up the installer and told it to upgrade.

The installer told me that some things may not be compatible with the upgrade, so I cancelled the install and ran the Upgrade Advisor.  I uninstalled the programs and removed the drivers it said were incompatible.

The upgrade got to the final step (restoring settings); it got to 92%, but I didn't feel like staring it anymore so I left the room.  When I came back, it had rebooted back into Vista with a note saying "Sorry, the upgrade failed."

I Googled a bit and found people had luck after uninstalling things like Wireshark and the ATI drivers.  Did that, tried again, still rolled back.

I looked in the logs, specifically `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupapi\setupapi.app.log`, and found the following line. (Each time I try to upgrade the Device in this line is different.  This is the most recent log entry, I didn't save the older ones.)

```
!    cci: !NCI: Op=BIND, Layer=NDIS, Upper=Tcpip6 Lower=\Device\{9A2D9804-A610-4D0B-8B8B-392406EE148F}, Error=00000019
```

I figured this was a problem with my network devices, so I uninstalled everything (from device manager) except my ethernet port and the WAN Miniports (I can't remove them, when I uninstall them from device manager, nothing happens).  I also unchecked IPv6 in my network card's property page.

This still didn't help, it still rolled back after I tried to upgrade.

I know I can (read: should) do a clean install, but I want to get this upgrade to work.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this upgrade work?  I have my graphics card (ATI) drivers uninstalled, all USB things unplugged, all network devices (except my ethernet port and WAN Miniports) uninstalled, all programs the Windows Upgrade Advisor told me to uninstall uninstalled.  What could be causing Windows to fail to upgrade and roll back to Vista?

P.S. Just now I found a list of all the Windows 7 upgrade log files: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927521.

P.P.S. Here is a copy of my `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\sources\Rollback\setuperr.log` (which oddly isn't on Microsoft's list of log files): http://pastebin.com/X03Azd5U.

**EDIT**: I took at look at `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log` and found this:

```
2011-10-03 22:19:03, Error      [0x080a97] MIG    HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32 [msacm.l3codecp] is not a valid registry value[gle=0x00000002]
2011-10-03 22:19:25, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}: BthMig: Failed to migrate bthport keys, bailing out
```

Some basic Googling found [this thread on Microsoft's forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-install-does-not-complete-possible/d8c9b91f-488a-4478-be3d-90a415f99358#d6948c00-3743-4cdb-bc30-877f9e51010b), maybe it'll help (see page 2).  I'm going to try setting `MIG_UPGRADE_IGNORE_PLUGINS` to `bthmigplugin.dll`, let's see what happens.

**EDIT 2**: Here is the full contents of `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log` (after running the upgrade with `MIG_UPGRADE_IGNORE_PLUGINS` set to `bthmigplugin.dll`): http://pastebin.com/ydKFRSL6

```
2011-10-04 23:24:18, Error                        Failed to find driver file path. Error=00000002x[gle=0x80092004]
```

**Edit 3**: I found another [SU thread](https://superuser.com/questions/36402/windows-7-fails-to-install/211674#211674): and as it suggested, installed WinDBG.  I did not have `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\setupmem.dmp`, but I did have `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupmem.dmp`.  I opened it up in WinDBG, and it said (Full output: http://pastebin.com/3476mx1m):

```
WINLOGON_FATAL_ERROR (c000021a)
The Winlogon process terminated unexpectedly.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff8a001f916c0, String that identifies the problem.
Arg2: 0000000000000001, Error Code.
Arg3: ffffffffc0000001
Arg4: 0000000000110bd8
```

**Edit 4**: I posted this on Microsoft's forums too: [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-upgrade-keeps-rolling-back-to-vista/9a9b5ba8-0541-4501-b32e-81de2ea9caea).

### Now we may be getting somewhere!

**Edit 5**: I looked in `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log`, which is a 136 MB log file, and I found something *actually* useful.

```
2011-10-10 21:20:34, Info                         [NdisCompl: Enter HrGetComponentID]
2011-10-10 21:20:34, Info                         ComponentID=ms_netbt_smb
2011-10-10 21:20:34, Info                         [NdisCompl: Exit HrGetComponentID]
2011-10-10 21:20:34, Info                         [NdisCompl: Enter HrGetComponentDriverFilePath]
2011-10-10 21:20:34, Error                        Failed to find driver file path. Error=00000002x[gle=0x80092004]
2011-10-10 21:20:34, Info                         [NdisCompl: Exit HrGetComponentDriverFilePath]


2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         [NdisCompl: Enter HrGetComponentID]
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         ComponentID=ms_rasman
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         [NdisCompl: Exit HrGetComponentID]
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         [NdisCompl: Enter HrGetComponentDriverFilePath]
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         ServiceName = RasMan
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         FilePathLen = 56
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         FilePath = C:\Windows\%SystemRoot%\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         Service Binary C:\Windows\%SystemRoot%\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs, is not a driver file
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Error                        Failed to find driver file path. Error=ffffffffx[gle=0x00000003]
2011-10-10 21:20:35, Info                         [NdisCompl: Exit HrGetComponentDriverFilePath]
```

I tried to do `netcfg -e -u ms_netbt_smb` and `netcfg -e -u ms_rasman`, but nothing happened.

```
C:\Users\NTICompass>netcfg -e -u ms_netbt_smb
Trying to uninstall ms_netbt_smb ...

...done.


C:\Users\NTICompass>netcfg -e -u ms_netbt_smb
Trying to uninstall ms_netbt_smb ...

...done.


C:\Users\NTICompass>
```

It doesn't seem to want to uninstall.  **How do I uninstall `ms_netbt_smb` and `ms_rasman`**?

**Edit 6**: I removed `ms_netbt_smb` and `ms_rasman` by looking through the registry and removing keys that referenced them.  Now my `setuperr.log` is blank, and I'm still getting the `cci: !NCI: Op=BIND, Layer=NDIS, Upper=Tcpip6` error.  I asked that as a separate question: [Upgrade to Windows 7 Rolls Back To Vista](https://superuser.com/q/350883/47650), as this one is getting kind of long and messy.

Comment: Windows Vista SP2 64-bit is this also Professional?

Comment: @JohnDR: It's actually Windows Vista Enterprise (64-bit, SP2), but I changed `EditionID` and `ProductName` in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` from "Enterprise" to "Business".  As a test, I did a fresh install of Vista Enterprise in VirtualBox, changed those keys to "Business" and tried to upgrade to 7.  That worked.

Comment: @Rocket - You also updated the virtual machine to SP2 right?  Otherwise your test wasn't accurate.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm 80% sure the Windows Vista Enterprise ISO I used was SP2.  Would SP2 cause problems with upgrading to Windows 7?

Comment: @Ramhound: My real machine has the [Platform Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644), which the VM didn't have.

Comment: @Rocket I believe that the problem, I hope the fix you came up with will work for you.

Comment: @JohnDR: Huh?  What fix are you talking about?

Comment: @Rocket the same fix you used to install it on your VM, I do not believe you can install a Professional upgrade onto a Enterprise system but if you can change the version information it should work on your computer as it did on your VM. Am I miss understanding your comment?

Comment: @JohnDR: I changed the registry in both my real installation and the VM.  The VM explanation was just to show the registry change worked.

Comment: Sorry this question is kinda long, I've been working with this for almost a week now (trying the upgrade once or twice each day).  It's really frustrating, and I'm so close to getting it working.

Comment: I've added some more details here.  I found something useful!

Comment: How do I uninstall `ms_netbt_smb` and `ms_rasman`?

Comment: Always a bad idea not doing a fresh install

Comment: @gd1: Yeah, I know.  I'm just crazy, so I want to get this working.  WTF would Microsoft include an upgrader if 95% of its problems are fixed by not using it?

Comment: @Rocket: that's a good question. The answer is: for market reasons. Telling customers: "hey guys, it's safe and easy to update, as 1-2-3" is better than saying: "OK guys, enjoy our OS but please do a fresh install". An OS is a chaotical system (in the mathematical sense of the term), for which the actual behaviour is often very, very hard to predict because of the many factors that play a role, and the billions of possible interactions between them. Reduce the chaoticity by performing safe procedures. Do a fresh install.

Comment: More, don't search for a solution now. Everything is probably already messed up. It's unrelevant what did actually happen, just take your data, perform a fresh install, restore the data and start to produce again. What advantage will you get if you solve this problem spending 20 hours of your time, which, assuming you're paid for example $25/hour, are $500 thrown in the W.C.? You can fresh install in 5 hours. You already wasted 50 reputation, if you care about it.

Comment: @gd1: I know I should clean install, and that dong that might relieve my frustration, but **I'm crazy** and I wanna get this to work (and I have like 200GB of data I'd need to backup).  I may just give up though, and do a clean install.

Comment: By the way, 200GB is nothing. You can buy 1TB for a few bucks... However, next time have the good habit to put the data on a different disk than the one Windows is installed into. It's insane to put all the stuff in the same disk.

Comment: @gd1: Thanks for the comments.  You totally made my day :-)  I may just give up for a while and continue using Vista, I don't even want 7 anyway (*hmph*) :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences between Vista and Windows 7 are rather minimal, using the same driver architecture, so the upgrade/downgrade should have worked.

It is of course possible that, as sometimes happens, upgrading your computer is impossible without a fresh install, but it is also possible that the conversion of Enterprise to Professional caused the problem.

Downgrade from Enterprise to Professional is not officially supported, but is possible through the registry hacks, as you did.

However, since you have a 64-bit version, the changes must be done in **two registry keys**:
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\`
`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.

As 64-bit Windows is really a mashup of 32-bit and 64-bit code, the problems could have arrived because only the 64-bit could be updated, as you have not hacked the registry key for 32-bit.

For more info see the article [Downgrade (Upgrade) Windows 7 Enterprise to Ultimate, Professional or Home Premium](http://www.mydigitallife.info/downgrade-upgrade-windows-7-enterprise-to-ultimate-professional-or-home-premium/), which also proposes the [Windows 7 Downgrader tool](http://www.deviantart.com/download/159805048/Windows_7_Enterprise_Downgrade_by_MP7000.zip) to do the job.

I suggest that you try to restore, if possible, Vista to a time before you started hacking, then use the Downgrader tool, reboot cleanly, check the above registry keys, and if everything is well try again the upgrade.

Try the Downgrader tool before trying the upgrade again, even if you cannot restore back the registry.

Comment: The weird thing is, I made a VM of Vista Enterprise 64-bit, I only changed the version string in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, and the upgrade to 7 Professional worked.  I think it's a driver issue, but yeah, most Vista drivers should just work on 7.  It's error is `Failed to find driver file path.`, wish I knew which driver it's referring to.

Comment: Did you try the Downgrader tool ? You could also try "sfc /scannow" in Vista to make sure everything is ok (need installation CD of same service pack as installed).

Comment: I'll give the Downgrader tool a shot, also `sfc /scannow` may help, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

Run the Windows 7 upgrade advisor, see if it flags any software or drivers, remove what is suggests before upgrading.

http://windows.microsoft.com/upgradeadvisor

Edit:

Here are the causes of the 21a error

Mismatched system files have been installed.

A Service Pack installation has failed.

A backup program that is used to restore a hard disk did not correctly restore files that may have been in use.

An incompatible third-party program has been installed.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156669) (not for Vista or W7 but may help diagnose)

.

Comment: I did that.  It suggested I remove GIMP, .NET framework 1.1, and a few other things.  It suggested I remove a few drivers too.  I remove all the things it said, but no dice.  It did say that Steam may not be compatible (which it obviously is), but I left that installed (no way am I re-installing all my games).  I doubt this is Steam's fault.  When I ran the upgrade, it told me that I should remove the ATI control center and install manager.  I removed all ATI drivers, but it's still telling me I should remove the install manager (thought I did).  Though I doubt that's the issue either.

Comment: Perform a clean boot and try upgrading again....http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/228/~/booting-clean-in-windows-7,-vista,-xp,-me-and-98#vista_7

Comment: Tried a clean boot, then the upgrade.  Didn't help :-(

Comment: What about using Windows' built-in "Administrator" account?

Comment: Check my edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from Vista to Windows 7 is like upgrading from Windows ME to Windows XP. It's possible and 1/100 may have some luck but still doesn't make it a good idea. I'd say, back up your data, format and do a fresh install.

Edited to make Ramhound happy.

EDITED: A rollback may also occur when the third-party driver Sptd.sys is installed on the computer. This driver is distributed with several applications such as Daemon Tools and Alcohol 120%. You can temporarily uninstall third-party CD/DVD Authoring or Virtualization software that could contain this driver before you upgrade the computer to Windows 7.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's what I should do, but why on earth does Microsoft even allow upgrades if they don't work? P.S. My Windows ME to Windows XP upgrade actually worked (guess I've used up my Windows Upgrade quota) :-)

Comment: Only possible sensitive answer.

Comment: This is a horrible answer.  I have see hundreds of computers been upgraded from Vista to Windows 7 without a single problem.

Comment: You may be right Ramhound, but obviously it's not successful for everyone. The hundreds of computers that you speak of may all be similar in the sense that they do not have the conflicting driver/hardware. I've never had issues with my computers with upgrading, but I do understand that many people will go several years without maintaining their hardware/software and can/will lead to failed upgrades.

Comment: `Sptd.sys`?  I /may/ have a third-party one installed, but the errors in the logs don't mention it, so I'm assuming that's not an issue.