# Upgrade to Windows 7 Rolls Back To Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

My [other question](https://superuser.com/q/342841/47650) was getting too long, and full of different problems, I figured I'd ask a new question.  I solved most of those issues, but I'm still having issues.

I'm still unable to upgrade from Vista to 7.  It gets to the last step (transferring settings/programs), and then rolls back.  I'm not sure at which percentage, because I'm not watching it for the 3 hours it takes.  I've seen it get to 92% once, then I went to bed.

My `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log` is completely blank, the only error I can find is in `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupapi\setupapi.app.log`:

```
!!!  dvi: Device not started: Device has problem: 0x0a: CM_PROB_FAILED_START.
!    cci: !NCI: Op=BIND, Layer=NDIS, Upper=Tcpip6 Lower=\Device\{CA085CB8-8ABE-423E-8CDD-50AF16A5D648}, Error=00000002
!    cci: !NCI: Op=BIND, Layer=NDIS, Upper=TCPIP6TUNNEL Lower=\Device\{CA085CB8-8ABE-423E-8CDD-50AF16A5D648}, Error=00000002
```

I followed [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852) to disable IPv6 in Vista, but that didn't seem to help.  I even tried to remove the network adapter from device manager before starting the install.  Still rolls back to Vista.

How can I remove these errors and *actaully* upgrade Vista to 7?

Comment: I would do a clean install of 7 after you back up your data, see if it succeeds.

Comment: Considering most OS installs are through the OEM, the upgrade setup tools are by far the least tested method.  I'd go with a clean install for time's sake.

Comment: Yeah, I know I *should* clean install, but I don't wanna... *whine*